# Character theory over integers

Tags: rt.representation-theory

This question comes from my notes, heavily edited, thus slightly unusual structure.

---

For Lie groups one can reformulate character theory as saying that

> **C** ⊗ K(`G`\ `pt`) = **C**[`T`/`W`] = **C**[ `X`<sup>*</sup> ]<sup>W</sup>

where `G` is the complex Lie group, `W` its Weyl group, `T` its torus. (subquestion: is this correct?)

For example, one can write the character theory of a torus and `SL`<sub>`2`</sub> as

> K(`G`<sub>`m`</sub>\ `pt`) = **Z**[`q`, `q`<sup>-1</sup>]     `and`     K(`SL`<sub>2</sub> \ `pt`) = **Z**[`q` + `q`<sup>-1</sup>].

**Question:** it's interesting that we're allowed to write **Z** in the examples above; I wonder if this works for any `G` in the formula above, e.g. if the isomorphism is valid over **Z** or **Q** rather then **C**?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The isomorphism works over Z.  The proof is that the basis change between W-symmetrized monomials and characters is upper-triangular with 1's on the diagonal.

Comment: I think I finally understand what canonical basis is, it's the generalization of this thing. Thanks!

Comment: Strangely, I don't see Scott Carnahan's answer, even though the answer with the text is prominently displayed in my "recent" tab.

Comment: He deleted it.  My guess is he misread the question; it's very unclear to me what connection you (or he) see between this question and the theory of canonical bases.

Comment: Ok! Then it's probably a SE bug that the name stays in the recent list and in the question. 